# Deploy spring boot war file to tomcat with ComponentScan other package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

My project structure below

```
com.example.demo
    demo1
        controller
            HelloController.java
        ApplicationSpringBoot.java
    demo2
        controller
            FooController.java
        service
            *Service.java
```

Here is my ApplicationSpringBoot.java

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
        "com.example.demo.demo1",
        "com.example.demo.demo2"
    })
    @EnableJpaRepositories({
        "com.example.demo.demo1",
        "com.example.demo.demo2"
    })
@EnableConfigurationProperties({
    FileStorageProperties.class
})
public class ApplicationSpringBoot extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationSpringBoot.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now i just type `mvn clean package` then it package to war file.
I deploy it to tomcat 9 and when i call to hello controller it works fine.
But call to FooController it return `404`.
My pom.xml file is packaging.type is war. And i using spring-boot-maven-plugin to build.
Any body can show me how to resolve?

Comment: Could you show us your FooController and how you are testing it?

Comment: i just add @RestController and @GetMapping(""). I make sure it working on run mvn spring-boot:run.